# Can I concatenate an ObservableCollection to an array containing the same type of objects?

Tags: c#, arrays, observablecollection

I have an array and an ObservableCollection of the same type of object and I want to join them together. Whenever I try and concatenate them though I just end up with the original number in the ObservableCollection.

```
    public class MyTest {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Registered { get; set; }
    }
```

---

```
        ObservableCollection<MyTest> test = new ObservableCollection<MyTest>()
        {
            new MyTest(){
                id = 1,
                Name = "Graham",
                Registered = true
            },
            new MyTest(){
                id = 2,
                Name = "Teresa",
                Registered = false
            }
        };

        MyTest[] myTest =  { 
            new MyTest(){
                id = 3,
                Name = "Keith",
                Registered = false
            },
            new MyTest(){
                id = 4,
                Name = "Emilie",
                Registered = false
            }
        };

        test.Concat(myTest);
```

Any suggestions on how to join these two together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the return value of `Concat()` as explained in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx):

**Return Value**

*An IEnumerable that contains the concatenated elements of the two input sequences.*

```
IEnumerable<MyTest> myTests = test.Concat(myTest);
// 'myTests' variable contains the concatenation of the two collections
```